# Do I need a visa to travel to Romania and Bulgaria if I have a Temporary Croatian Residence permit?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, pakistani-citizens, romania, bulgaria

I am from Pakistan and I have a Croatian temporary residence permit as an Erasmus student.

I want to travel from Zagreb to Romania and Bulgaria for a short visit: do I need a tourist visa in those cases?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=PK&AR=HR&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=BG&DE=RO&selDest=Bulgaria%0D%0ARomania&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

**Bulgaria:**

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a residence permit
>   issued by Croatia for a maximum stay of 90 days

**Romania**

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a residence permit
>   issued by Croatia for a maximum stay of 90 days

So no, you do **not** need visas for these countries. Just present your passport and residence permit card at the border.